# Simulation of closed volume getting error in simulation part

Tags: modelica, dymola

I modelled a compressor that gives air at a constant mass flow rate of 0.1 kg/s. I used a closed volume (fluid library) to store the air.
When translated there was no error but when I do simulation, I am getting the following error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I cleaned up the tags, you are using Modelica (language) in Dymola (tool). Please do not add tags for the tools jmodelica, openmodelica, pymodelica if you are not using them.

Comment: The error you get is coming from a nonlinear iteration using Brent's method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method This is used in the fluid properties, in your case here it seems like pressure and entropy are given, and the tool is trying to find temperature.